# Having trouble writing an equation with complex exponents in C#

Tags: c#, math, visual-studio-2019, equation

I have done some research and can't seem to find what I need.  It may be an easy fix but I am stumped. I am trying to write and equation in c# and it is returning a NaN value for me and I don't know why.
I have posted my code below as well as a picture of the original equation. Any help would be appreciated, I don't believe I am entering the equation correctly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int playerLevel;
        double experience = 1;
        WriteLine("Please Enter Your Current Level: ");
        playerLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        try
        {
            experience = 1 / 8 * (Math.Pow(playerLevel, 2) - playerLevel + 600 * ((Math.Pow(2, Convert.ToDouble(playerLevel/7)) - Math.Pow(2, Convert.ToDouble(1/7))) / (Math.Pow(2, Convert.ToDouble(1/7)) - 1)));
            WriteLine("Your current Experience is: " + experience);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            WriteLine(err.Message);
            throw;
        }
        ReadKey();
    }
```

[Original Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehb6q.png)

Comment: Use `1.0/7.0` etc rather than first doing an integer division and then trying to convert that to double. 1/7 is zero. Always write doubles as doubles without converts.

Comment: Have you debugged your code, what line is throwing the error?

Comment: I would suggest that you split up the one line equation into multiple smaller calculations with some good named variables. It would also make the debugging easier.

Comment: You should decompose using intermediate vars this horrible one big line to be able to see things as well as debug...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is the culprit:
`/ (Math.Pow(2, Convert.ToDouble(1 / 7)) - 1)`

- `1/7` is 0.
- 2^0 is 1
- 1 - 1 is 0
- you're dividing by zero, giving you NaN.

Consider just writing `1.0/7.0` instead of `Convert.ToDouble(1 / 7)`

The part that likely tripped you up is that `1/7` is **zero** because it's integer division.  `1` is an integer and `7` is an integer, so the `/` will use integer division, giving `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Add ".0" or "d" after all your numbers to indicate that they are not integers.
For example, write "1.0" instead of "1".